# Reiniciar script após função load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Queria saber como faço pra utilizar meu script dentro do conteúdo que irá ser carregado pela função `load()`.

**A função:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submenu').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.page-wrapper').load($(this).data('href'));
    });
});
```

**Os elementos (esboço):**

```
<section class="page-wrapper">
    <h1> Hello, guys! </h1>
    <p> Este é um exemplo do conteúdo da página </p>

    <ol class="menu">
        <li><a class="submenu" data-href="www.example.com" href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a class="submenu" data-href="www.example.com" href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
        <li><a class="submenu" data-href="www.example.com" href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Ou seja, o menu sempre irá carregar via `load()`. Com isso meu *script* não funciona nos elementos que são incorporados à minha "página principal". Como corrijo esse defeito?

Comment: Phellipe, porque não usa faz o bind usando a função `on`? Ela garante que futuros elementos que serão adicionados ao DOM e que satisfaçam esse seletor.

Comment: alterei a função para `$('.submenu').on('click', function(e){...});` e o resultado não mudou. '-'

Comment: Será que algum outro fato está causando isso? Como o template engine do Framework CodeIgniter por exemplo !?!

Comment: Esse Javascript é executado no carregamento da página, onde após um tempo esse esboço é carregado por Ajax? Tentou especificar melhor o seletor (`.submenu a`) porque o seletor age sobre o `<ul>` e não sobre o `<a>`?

Comment: Errei ao fazer o esboço. O selector está no lugar correto.

Comment: O layout está implementado com um template engine. Ele está dividido em `Layout.php` (footer, header e carrega o content), Content.php (esse é o content que é demonstrado no esboço acima. Ele também carrega a sidebar) & `Sidebar.php` (esse é o menu que dentro contém os `li` que uso como selector.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegue o tratamento do evento para um ancestral que seja permanente na página:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.page-wrapper').on('click', '.submenu', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.page-wrapper').load($(this).data('href'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah... Estava postando uma resposta com esse exato código, muito bom. Aqui vai um JSFiddle que usei para testar: http://jsfiddle.net/tLez982n/.

Comment: @Wakim Desculpe... :( É que eu sabia a resposta e resolvi postar logo...

Comment: Que isso, sem problemas, acabei demorando muito fazendo o teste hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Recentemente tive o mesmo problema com o projeto aqui da empresa que é totalmente dependente de ajax, única forma de resolver foi executa-los novamente.

> Note que antes de bindar o clique eu desbindo, evitando duplicidade de cliques.

```
 function scripts() {
        $('.submenu').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.page-wrapper').load($(this).data('href'));
        });
    }

    $(document).ajaxComplete(scripts);
```